# Inserting in Specified cell in Excel using Open XML

Tags: c#, xml

Can anyone help me as to how can I insert a value into a specified cell in an excel sheet using Open XML in C#? For example I want to insert into row 'E10' in an Excel sheet how can I do it? I am using Open XML SDK v2.0.

Comment: can you show us the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can use the E[xcel Helper Library](http://ehl.codeplex.com/) for this. Something like this:-

```
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(1, 1, "test1,1"));
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(1, 2, "test1,2"));
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(2, 2, "test2,2"));
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(2, 3, "test2,3"));
```